# Not able to start websphere server 8 in Rational application developer 8

Tags: java, websphere, rad

I am using Websphere application server 8.0.0.2 and Rational application developer(RAD- 8.0.4)

When i try to start the WAS from RAD servers tab. It worked fine for two to three times and later it started giving

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: RESOURCE
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RESOURCE
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:665)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:644)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
Could not find the main class: RESOURCE.  Program will exit.
```

I reinstalled WAS and tried, it was working fine, i was able to start the server properly for 1 or 2 times, then again the same error after i reopened RAD.

Please help.

Comment: Check if WAS is already running, go to Task Manager -> Processes and look for java.exe, if you find java.exe kill the process and try restarting the server.

Comment: @Apurv : I checked the task manager, there is no java.exe, In RAD it prints the above error in console till the server times out.

Answer (score 0):

Trying cleaning the server:

Go to the servers view, right click on the server and select "Clean...".  This dumps all the cached application and state files.  This will then start the server and publish whatever project is on it.

Comment: When i say clean after removing all the ears, it again leads to the same error.